# How I can log all nodejs messages showed on console to syslog in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am new to nodejs and syslog functionality.
The message generated by nodejs such as error, or info are not getting logged in syslog.
I want to log all the message generated by nodejs and displayed on the terminal to syslog. 
For this what changes I need to do in syslog.conf file?
Note: I dont want to use Winston, loggly or log4s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also wanted console messages from a Node server written to syslog, without having to use a specific library within my code. The quickest way seems to be [redirecting the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124455/linux-how-to-redirect-stdout-stderr-to-logger) on the terminal:

```
nodejs ~/myapp.js 2>&1 | logger &
```

Or if the app is launched from a more complex bash script, then entire output of the [script can be redirected](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/) to syslog by adding this at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as to what Syslog is as I am not an Ubuntu user. But You may want to use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). Not only it will serve your purpose but also it's asynchronous.

Comment: Winston is a good option but I don't want to use it. I I have to use that I have to change my code then and code is too big so I can not change it.So, any other suggestions ?